# How to find out the progress of playing an audio file?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, audio, android-mediaplayer

How can I find out the progress of playback in order to display it in the progress bar.
Here is my code to play.

```
            var player = new MediaPlayer();
            player.SetDataSource(filename);
            player.SetVolume(10, 10);
            player.Prepare();
            player.Start();               
            try
            {
                while (!token.IsCancellationRequested && player.IsPlaying)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(100, token);
                    }
                    catch (System.OperationCanceledException) { }
                }
            }
            catch (System.OperationCanceledException)
            {

            }
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're using the Android MediaPlayer class. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.media.mediaplayer?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9)

Have you tried `player.CurrentPosition` ?

Comment: Thanks for the help.
It’s enough for me to work with the duration property.

Comment: No problem. You shouldn't be shy to find out more about the classes you work with. I'm sure that if you read some methods and properties about the MediaPlayer class, you'll learn a lot more too.